# HQL doesn't return Object

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want my HQL to return Object instead of array, because I use some join tables and when I write a query including column names of joined tables, HQL gives array list instead of object. I found that we should use `new` to make it object.

```
SELECT new Accommodation(a.name, a.rank, ap.pic) FROM Accommodation AS a INNER JOIN a.accommodationPics AS ap WHERE ap.isPromoPic = 1 AND a.cbState.stateName = :stateName
```

I have tried this so far and got error: `'Accommodation' cannot be resolved to a type.`. Is there something wrong?

**Update**

New query: `SELECT new ba.reservation.pojo.Accommodation(a.name, a.rank, ap) FROM Accommodation AS a INNER JOIN a.accommodationPics AS ap WHERE ap.isPromoPic = 1 AND a.cbState.stateName = :stateName`

```
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 200)
private String name;

@Column(name = "rank")
private int rank;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "accommodationBean", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<AccommodationPic> accommodationPics;

public Accommodation(String _name, int _rank, ArrayList<AccommodationPic> _pic) {
    this.rank = _rank;
    this.name = _name;
    this.accommodationPics = _pic;
}
```

Comment: 1. As simas_ch says: Add complete path about your class Accomodation. 2. Have you defined the correct constructor about Accomodation?

Comment: @JoeTaras I  just have a default constructor for Accommodation.

Comment: You must add a costructor with (Type1, Type2, Type3) with 3 types of your query

Comment: Tell me if it's OK, so I can create an answer for future community consult

Comment: @JoeTaras It is sort of OK but I started getting 404 from ajax after I did what you told me. I edited the question just to show you what I did so far.

Comment: 404 can be returned by a request. But Sql side that's OK. I suppose you must open another question about Ajax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About this query:

There are two order of errors:

The first (as simas_ch said):

When you use a new Object (in your case, `Accomodation`) you must fully qualified your Object with all namespace path

The second:

You must defined a properly constructor in your pojo definition.

If you write this:

```
new Accommodation(a.name, a.rank, ap.pic)
```

You must have in `Accomodation` class a constructor like this:

```
public Accommodation(String name, int rank, a.name, ArrayList<AccommodationPic> pic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.pic = pic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accommodation must be fully qualified with the full package name before the class name.

Comment: You mean this l believe: `ba.reservation.pojo.Accommodation`. If so, this also gives the same error.